# Are screen protectors necessary on cameras with "flippable" screens (like the Canon 60D)?

Tags: equipment-protection, lcd

I suppose that photographers mainly use screen protectors for keeping screens free from scratches because of bags and other things.

I wonder whether screen protectors are still needed on Canon 60D while it has flippable screen that gets best protection possible when packed into a bag.

Are there any protective screens for this camera in the first place? And do they prevent the screen from being back flipped (screen facing body)?

Comment: I've just had a double downvote on my answer. Not useful apparently. The question is a good one BUT is both specific and general.It asks about screen protectors for camera with flippable screens **BUT** then gives an example of a specific camera (and by possible implication a libe of cameras) which happens to have a factory fitted low cost replaceable potector in place. This is not the norm in cameras that fit the general description. Some or most answer have focused in on this special case making my answer less applicable but mot other answers, arguably, wrong in the general case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that the actual screen on Canon cameras is already mounted behind a rather solid transparent plastic plate from the factory, third-party screen protectors are not actually screen protectors.

They are screen protector protectors.

Comment: +1. These really aren't needed unless you are especially abusive to your equipment. (If they _were_, they'd come in the box.)

Comment: Ok but are they changeable? Cause if they're not it's probably still good to have something on that can be changed? Or...

Comment: Yes they are. A piece of Canon-branded plastic, fastened with double-sided tape of all things! Not very expensive either.

Comment: @Staale where can you purchase replacements for the built-in screen replacements? Do you know the approximate cost?

Comment: It's a standard Canon spare part... a camera shop ought to be able to round one up for you, or one can be ordered off the net. You may find this link interesting: http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=922334 . Finding out the exact part number is the biggest problem I think.

Comment: @Staale I know that my local camera shop was able to get out a huge stock list and get the specific part number of the 1000D eyepiece rubber when I needed a new one around 12 months ago, so it's not improbable that other Canon dealers will have a similar list.

Comment: @Staale S: As I see it it's not that easy to change this protector now is it?

Comment: It ain't what I'd call rocket science :)

Comment: Your answer focuses on a special case exdample which just happens to be one model or range of cameras from one manufacturer. This is an example of why specific equipment questions are frowned on when generic questions are asked. Your answer is fine for eg a Canon 60D and very poor for eg a Sonly SLT-A77V. (ask me how I know :-( ).

Comment: **FYI**: I've had my 60D for a number of years and screen is still as good as new. No scratches no nothing. All this despite the fact that I regularly forget to fold it to the inside...

Answer (score 4):

It's good to have a screen protector for camera LCD even if you have a flippable one. This will ensure you don't get the oil from your nose onto the LCD while looking through the viewfinder. This way you wont be afraid to push your eye closer. I used to look through the viewfinder from several inches away just because I didn't want to ruin the LCD screen with scratches and oils, that was before I got the protector. Also if you have a wife/girl friend who wears nose-pin, screen protector is a **must** before you let them use the camera!

If you don't get a screen protector built specificly for your camera, you can buy one made for large-screen cell phones (I used the one which was designed for iPhone) and cut it to your  camera screen size. Search for '**Lexard TruVue**' screen protectors, they make some good products for cameras.

Comment: Oil might be annoying, but it won't actually damage the screen, and it's going to be just as an not (or possibly more so) on a screen protector.

Answer (score 1):

Many cameras with flippable screens do not have manufacturer provided LCD protectors. For example:

- **Some do:** The Canon 60D given as an 'example only' in the question title does have a protector when sold.
- **Some don't:** The Sony A77V (Sony's top APSC DSLR when introduced) does not have a protector attached as standard. I imagine (without having checked) that if the A77 does not have a protector fitted when new then most or all other Sony cameras would not have either.

If your camera does not have a manufacturer provided LCD protector and the surface of the LCD is not replaceable at a cost which you consider reasonable compared to the effort and effects and cost of fitting a screen protector, then you need one.

The comment was made

- "These really aren't needed unless you are especially abusive to your equipment."

To that I'd add. "If you ...

- **NEVER** have something in your camera bag that may accidentally scratch
  (if not actually gouge bend fold staple or mutilate) the screen,
- **NEVER** accidentally swing or brush it against something that is apparently harder than diamond even though it looked soft,
- **NEVER** lend it to someone (or have them hold it for the briefest moment, who turns out to unexpectedly be an anarchist camera screen scraper - or just typically less careful than you are,
- **NEVER**  put it down and have it roll unexpectedly or have something slid against it or
- **NEVER** have {add unexpected real world LCD damaging event(s) here} happen".

Then, in such cases, I agree, you PROBABLY will get away without having one.
Otherwise .... .

---

**LCD movement obstruction by screen protector:**

Re "Are there any protective screens for this camera in the first place? And do they prevent the screen from being back flipped (screen facing body)?"

There are generic "stick on" protectors that will fit most screens, or larger ones can be cut down to fit any screen. While some protectors are made of clip on hard plastic which may prevent some screen articulation modes, the stick on ones are so thin that they are extremely unlikely to prevent available screen motion.

The Sony SLT A77 is a good example of a camera with an extremely well articulated screen - if a stick on protectordoes not obstruct movement on this screen it's reasonably unlikely to do so on others. The A77 has a screen with an "arm with two joints with the arm to LCD joint allowing 180 degree pivoting  at the screen attachment point. 'Stick on' protectors cause no problems.

**6000 words:**

[image]

Comment: Double phantom downvoters - the question is a generic one with an example only given which happens to be an exception to the rule. The answer is useful wrt the actual question asked. FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

you could flip your screen over, so that the plastic side is faced towards you. But since the obvious downside is that you can't preview your pics anymore, no one will ever do this anyway. :-)

Comment: I indeed never use the screen on my camera while shooting. After a session (or during a break) I may use it to make a quick review of things that need reshooting at times, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is NO.
Now it is up to anybody to decide if this will be used or not.
I don't use one and I have no scratches on the screen.
Simply take care of it. It you store it you can flip it on the non screen side outside and voilà. :)